# How to pass PHP Object to Python and Vice Versa

Tags: php, python, serialization

I am attempting to develop a functionality that involves 3 programs.

Program A (Python): Places a GET request to Program B.

Program B (PHP): Processes the request from Program A and gives it to Program C.

Program C (Python): Processes the data from Program B and returns an object to Program B.

In the end, the execution flow I want is as follows:

> A (data) -> B (data) -> C (data) -> C (object) -> B (object) -> A
>   (object)

So how can I "transfer/pass" a Python/PHP object between the two languages?

Does it involve some sort of object serialization?

**UPDATE:**
To be more specific, the data that I want to transfer is a class object created in python. i.e.:

```
class Foo:
def __init__(self):
    data = 42
    name = 'Bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to exchange objects between Python an PHP, let's say for example sending a Python dictionary to a PHP and it reads it as an Array, then you can consider using a RPC serialization framework such as:

- [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/)
- [Protocol buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
- [Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/)

Comment: Would these suggested solutions work for object data specifically? (not just arrays/dics) (see updated question)